# Trying to add objects to vector and display the results but its not working getting a seg fault

Tags: c++

I am trying to add my objects added on the heap to my vector but i cannot seem to get them to add, calculate and display the results. I am getting a segmen fault when I display the results. I want the objects to be added to the vector then I want to calculate the pay and display the results. What am I doing wrong to cause the seg fault?

Main file

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include "Employee.h"

using namespace std;


int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    vector<Employee *> myVector(4);
    Employee *emp1 = new Employee("Joe", 15.0, 45.0);
    Employee *emp2 = new Employee("Sally", 25.0, 35.0);
    Employee *emp3 = new Employee("Mary", 32.0, 55.0);
    Employee *emp4 = new Employee("John", 18.0, 32.0);
    
    myVector.push_back(emp1);
    myVector.push_back(emp2);
    myVector.push_back(emp3);
    myVector.push_back(emp4);
    
    for (int i = 0; i <= myVector.size() - 1; i++)
    {
        myVector[i]->calculatePay();
        myVector[i]->display();
    }
    

    return 0;
}
```

Header file

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
#ifndef EMPLOYEE_H
#define EMPLOYEE_H

class Employee {
public:
    string name;
    double payRate;
    double hours;
    double gross;
    Employee * next;
    
    Employee();
    Employee(string name, double payRate, double hours);
    void display();
    void calculatePay();
    Employee(const Employee& orig);
    virtual ~Employee();
private:

};

#endif /* EMPLOYEE_H */
```

Source File

```
#include <iomanip>
#include "Employee.h"

Employee::Employee() {
    
    name = "";
    payRate = 0.0;
    hours = 0.0;
    gross = 0.0;
    
    
}
Employee::Employee(string name, double payRate, double hours)
{
    this->name = name;
    this->payRate = payRate;
    this->hours = hours;
}
void Employee::display()
{
    cout << setprecision(2) << fixed << endl;
    cout << "Name: " << name << endl;
    cout << "Pay Rate: " << payRate << endl;
    cout << "Hours: "  << hours << endl;
    cout << "Gross: "  << gross << endl;
}
void Employee::calculatePay()
{
    if (hours > 40)
    {
        gross = ((hours - 40) * payRate * 1.5) + (40 * payRate);
    }
    else
    {
        gross = hours * payRate;
    }
}

Employee::Employee(const Employee& orig) {
}

Employee::~Employee() {
}
```

Comment: `Employee * next;` is uninitialized, but probably not the cause since it doesn't look like it's used at all.

Comment: Also. both `#include <iostream>` and `using namespace std;` don't belong in that header.

Comment: `i <= myVector.size() - 1` would be wrong for empty vector, `i < myVector.size()`, or simply for-range.

Comment: not the issue, but you should avoid loop conditions ala `i <= myVector.size() - 1`, because they will fail for empty vectors (`size` is unsigned). Use `i < myVector.size()` and when you actually have to subtract 1 prefer `i + 1 < myVector.size()`

Comment: also not the current issue: your copy constructor is not copying anything. You should let the compiler generate it.

Comment: as an illustration: change `vector<int *> myVector(4);` --> `vector<int *> myVector;` https://godbolt.org/z/6xPWa6Ex3

Comment: If you are using C++11 onwards, you can shorten your initialization. e.g. `std::vector<Employee *> myVector { new Employee("Joe", 15.0, 45.0) };`

Comment: `Employee::Employee(const Employee& orig) {}` -- Never create stubbed-out user-defined copy constructors.  The compiler is expecting that your user-defined version actually makes copies.  Otherwise you've opened yourself up for some of the hardest-to-find bugs in C++.  If you create a user-defined copy constructor, you have to live up to the contract that your function makes correct copies.

Answer (score 6):

The declaration of vector

```
vector<Employee *> myVector(4);
```

is telling it to allocate 4 elements. The elements are initialized to `nullptr`. Using [`push_back()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) will add elements after the null elements.

After that, at the line

```
myVector[i]->calculatePay();
```

the `nullptr` is dereferenced and lead to Segmentation Fault.

You should remove the argument for the constructor of vector to create an empty vector. If you want to reserve space for `push_back()` beforehand, you should use [`reserve()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve)

```
vector<Employee *> myVector;
myVector.reserve(4);
```

Also the loop

```
for (int i = 0; i <= myVector.size() - 1; i++)
```

is not bad (for this case that the vector is not empty), but not in the usual way. It should be:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < myVector.size(); i++)
```